# Am I calculating the median for my dataset correctly?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting, median, percentile

I am trying to produce a column within ssrs 2012 that displays the median cost.

I have been searching this for a while, and have written a PERCENTILE_CONT query to try and achieve this.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT srt.Name,
    cast(sum(sr.price) as int) as AvgCost,
    cast(sum(sr.cost) as int) as AvgTransCost,
    cast(avg(sr.TotalTimeSpent) as int) as TotalTimeSpent,
    percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sum(sr.price)) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name) AS MedianSpend
from 
    ServiceReq sr, ServiceReqTemplate srt
```

When I run the report, these are the results:
[image: If you look at the very last row, you'll notice the avgcost is $46, and the cost median is $46.25]

is this the median? Why are all of the other avgcosts and medians the same? If I change the PERCENTILE_CONT(.5) to PERCENTILE_CONT(.9), there is no change in the Median column - which leads me to believe this is the incorrect values for the median :(

Comment: Replace ORDER BY sum(sr.price) with ORDER BY sr.price perhaps?

Comment: I tried that and when I did, it gave me the "sr.price is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `PERCENTILE_CONT` (CONT = continuous)

Calculates a percentile based on a continuous distribution of the column value in SQL Server. The result is interpolated and might not be equal to any of the specific values in the column.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231473.aspx)

Whereas what you want is `PERCENTILE_DISC` (DISC = discrete)

For a given percentile value P, `PERCENTILE_DISC` sorts the values of the expression in the ORDER BY clause and returns the value with the smallest CUME_DIST value (with respect to the same sort specification) that is greater than or equal to P. For example, `PERCENTILE_DISC (0.5)` will compute the 50th percentile (that is, the median) of an expression.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231327.aspx)

Comment: I just added the DISC where CONT is and it gave me the same results.

Comment: How do I remove the sum(sr.price) without causing an aggregate function error?